# processing the data in forms.py django before saving

Tags: python, django, forms

This is a class in my forms.py
What I want to do is: 
there are two fields on this form- admin_time and execution_time . I want to do a comparison to the data before saving.

```
if admin_time:
  execution_time=admin_time
```

This is what I intend to achieve.

```
class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
keywords = (forms.CharField(
            help_text=_('Please use commas to separate your keywords.'),
            required=False,
            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'medium-field'})))
admin_time = forms.CharField(
            help_text=_('Enter If more than 60 minutes.'),
            required=False,
            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'fill-width'}))

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['instance']:
        initial = kwargs.get('initial', {})
        initial['keywords'] = kwargs['instance'].keywords_list
        kwargs['initial'] = initial
    super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def _process_keywords(self, creator):
    if 'keywords' in self.changed_data:
        kw = [k.strip() for k in self.cleaned_data['keywords'].split(',')]
        self.instance.replace_keywords(kw, creator)

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(TaskForm, self).clean()
    start_date = cleaned_data.get('start_date')
    end_date = cleaned_data.get('end_date')
    if start_date and end_date:
        if start_date >= end_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("'End date' must be after 'Start date'"))
    return cleaned_data

def save(self, creator, *args, **kwargs):
    self.instance.creator = creator
    super(TaskForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if kwargs.get('commit', True):
        self._process_keywords(creator)
    return self.instance

class Media:
    css = {
        'all': ('css/admin_ace.css',)
    }

class Meta:
    model = Task
    fields = ('name', 'short_description', 'execution_time', 'difficulty',
              'priority', 'repeatable', 'team', 'project', 'type', 'start_date',
              'end_date', 'why_this_matters', 'prerequisites', 'instructions',
              'is_draft', 'is_invalid')
    widgets = {
        'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 100, 'class': 'fill-width'}),
        'short_description': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 100, 'class': 'fill-width'}),
        'instructions': AceWidget(mode='markdown', theme='textmate', width='800px',
                                  height='300px', wordwrap=True,
                                  attrs={'class': 'fill-width'}),
        'start_date': CalendarInput,
        'end_date': CalendarInput,
        'why_this_matters': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 2, 'class': 'fill-width'}),
        'prerequisites': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 4, 'class': 'fill-width'}),
    }
```

What I tried is adding this function:

```
 def _execution_time(self):
    cleaned_data = super(TaskForm, self).clean()
    data = cleaned_data.get('execution_time')
    admin_time = cleaned_data.get('admin_time')
    if admin_time:
        data=admin_time
    return data
```

But its not working. Wanted help on this.

Comment: "But there's something wrong." What, specifically, is wrong?

Comment: where are you calling execution time? What happens if you move the execution_time logic to your clean method?

Comment: What I meant is: This validation doesn't seem to happen on my code. Even if admin_time is present, what I can see on the next detail.html page is execution_time only.

Comment: @dm03514 can you brief what you meant? you mean adding the code to def clean(self): function?

Answer (score 0):

well, the method name should not be `_execution_time(self)`, it should be `clean_execution_time(self)` for it to be executed. For details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/validation/